# SQLAlchemy python order_by parent's parent's attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a difficult situation when ordering. I have a 3 deep relationship as follows:

```
fight 1->M participant 1->M action
```

I need to order a list of actions by the fight id. I cannot find a way to do this.

```
class fight(db.Model):
    fight_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fight_name = db.Column('fight_name')

class participant(db.Model):
    participant_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    participant_name = db.Column('participant_name')
    fight_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("fight.fight_id"))
    fight = db.relationship('fight', innerjoin=True)

class action(db.Model):
    action_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    participant_party_1 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("participant.participant_id"))
    participant_1 = db.relationship('participant', foreign_keys=[participant_1])
    participant_party_2 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("participant.participant_id"))
    participant_2 = db.relationship('participant', foreign_keys=[participant_2])
```

I am trying to do something like this?

```
action.query.order_by(action.<participant>.<fight_id>).all()
```

I really need to do it by participant_1 and participant_2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the complete answer for me, but it's the right approach.

```
action.query.join(participant, action.participant_party_1 == participant.participant_id).join(fight, participant.fight_id == fight.fight_id).order_by(fight.fight_id).order_by(action.attack_order).all()
```

Much appreciation to @IanWilson, but I found a simpler answer for my situation. You got me to looking in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to the `Participant` model and then you can use that in your query.  I sorted fight id by `DESC` to make sure it was working.

```py
q = session.query(Action).join(Action.participant_1).order_by(Participant.fight_id.desc(), Action.participant_party_1, Action.participant_party_2)
```

Here is a larger example, I changed some of the model because I had problems getting it working:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Text,
    Integer,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
    UniqueConstraint,
    update,
    DateTime,
   Date,
    Boolean,
    LargeBinary,
    nullslast,
    Index,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Table,
    Column,
    MetaData,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, and_, or_, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/dbname', echo=False)

class Fight(Base):
    __tablename__ = "fights"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Participant(Base):
    __tablename__ = "participants"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fight_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("fights.id"))
    fight = relationship('Fight', innerjoin=True)

class Action(Base):
    __tablename__ = "actions"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    participant_party_1 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("participants.id"))
    participant_1 = relationship('Participant', foreign_keys=[participant_party_1])
    participant_party_2 = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("participants.id"))
    participant_2 = relationship('Participant', foreign_keys=[participant_party_2])


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    f1 = Fight(name="Sunday")
    session.add(f1)
    f2 = Fight(name="Monday")
    session.add(f2)
    p1 = Participant(name="P1", fight=f1)
    p2 = Participant(name="P2", fight=f1)
    p3 = Participant(name="P3", fight=f2)
    p4 = Participant(name="P4", fight=f2)
    session.add_all([p1, p2, p3, p4])
    for action in range(5):
        session.add(Action(participant_1=p1, participant_2=p2))
    for action in range(3):
        session.add(Action(participant_1=p3, participant_2=p4))

    q = session.query(Action).join(Action.participant_1).order_by(Participant.fight_id.desc(), Action.participant_party_1, Action.participant_party_2)

    for action in q.all():
        print (action.participant_1.fight_id, action.participant_party_1, action.participant_party_2, action.id)
```

Output from the larger example

```
2 3 4 6
2 3 4 7
2 3 4 8
1 1 2 4
1 1 2 1
1 1 2 5
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 3
```

Comment: What is Base in this code?

Comment: @DannyEllisJr.  Declarative base, `declarative_base`, I think your `db.Model`.   I added the setup for the example code.   Is `db.Model` from flask ?

Comment: db = SQLAlchemy(app)  Model is from SQLAlchemy

Comment: This approach, using session.query vs. my approach db.Model, seems to be totally different ways of doing the same thing. I'm guessing one is an older approach and one is newer, but I don't know which is which. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: I should have said from flask-SQLAlchemy

Comment: @DannyEllisJr.   It should be the same idea. I don't think one is new or old, more like they are in parallel.  Really all that matter is the query itself which should almost be the same.